# how to display html data or CData in UIWEbview?

Tags: iphone

I have got data from the server like 'my name is &nbsp john'. I want to display in `UIWebView` like 'my name is john'.
How to display it?

Comment: Are you from ahmedabad, india?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`- loadHTMLString:baseURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:) method.

Answer (score 0):

To load remote html file:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]]];
```

To load local html file:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

To load html string:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<img src=test.png>" baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```